# Typescript: determine object type from property in object's property

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, conditional-types

I might be asking too much of Typescript, but I was wondering if something like this is possible:

```
interface ObjectType {
    type: 'this' | 'that';
}

interface SomeObject {
    objType: ObjectType
}

interface ThisObject extends SomeObject {
    objType: { type: 'this' }
    thisProp: 'anything'
}

interface ThatObject extends SomeObject {
    objType: { type: 'that' }; 
    thatProp: 'something'
}

function getProp(obj: ThisObject | ThatObject) {
    switch (obj.objType.type) {
        case 'this':
            return {
                type: obj.objType.type,
                prop: obj.thisProp
            };
        case 'that':
            return {
                type: obj.objType.type,
                prop: obj.thatProp
            };
    }
}
```

Typescript is able to correctly narrow `obj.objType.type`, but the value I'm trying to assign to `prop` in the returned object doesn't typecheck. Errors are the same for both (obviously with different property names):

```
TS2339: Property 'thatProp' does not exist on type 'ThisObject | ThatObject'. Property 'thatProp' does not exist on type 'ThisObject'.
```

Is something like this possible? I also tried something like this:

```
interface SomeObject {
    objType: ObjectType;
    thisProp: SomeObject['objType'] extends 'this' ? 'anything' : never;
    thatProp: SomeObject['objType'] extends 'that' ? 'something' : never;
}
```

which results in both props being `never`, as well as something like this:

```
type PickObject<T> = T extends 'this' ? ThisObject : ThatObject;

function getProp<T extends 'this' | 'that'>(obj: PickObject<T>) {
    switch (obj.objType.type) {
        case 'this':
            return {
                type: obj.objType.type,
                prop: obj.thisProp
            };
        case 'that':
            return {
                type: obj.objType.type,
                prop: obj.thatProp
            };
    }
}
```

which results in the same error:

```
TS2339: Property 'thisProp' does not exist on type 'PickObject '.
```

Comment: Can you fix your interfaces?  Presumably you need something like `interface ThisObject extends SomeObject { objType: { type: 'this' }; thisProp: 'anything' }` and
`interface ThatObject extends SomeObject { objType: { type: 'that' }; thatProp: 'something' }`.  That wouldn't make [nested discriminated unions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) magically work, unfortunately, but at least your types would correspond to what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your types are actually like this:

```
interface ThisObject extends SomeObject { objType: { type: 'this' }; thisProp: 'anything' }
interface ThatObject extends SomeObject { objType: { type: 'that' }; thatProp: 'something' }
```

where the `type` properties are actually nested inside an `objType` property, then you run into the issue filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758) where nested [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) are not really supported in TypeScript.  You can’t use a discriminated union as a discriminant in another discriminated union; a discriminant must be a union of singleton types like `"this" | "that"`.

---

Instead of waiting around for microsoft/TypeScript#18758 to get addressed, you could write your own [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that behaves like a nested discriminated union discriminator by passing a discriminant *object* and using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) to represent the desired narrowing.  Something like this:

```
function nestedDiscrim<T extends object | PropertyKey, D extends object | PropertyKey>(
  val: T, discriminant: D): val is Extract<T, D>;
function nestedDiscrim(val: any, discriminant: any) {
  if ((typeof val === "object") && (typeof discriminant === "object")) {
    for (let k in discriminant) {
      if (!(k in val)) return false;
      if (!nestedDiscrim(val[k], discriminant[k])) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  if ((typeof val !== "object") && (typeof discriminant !== "object")) {
    return val === discriminant;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
function getProp(obj: ThisObject | ThatObject) {
  if (nestedDiscrim(obj, { objType: { type: "this" } } as const)) {
    return {
      type: obj.objType.type,
      prop: obj.thisProp
    };
  } else {
    return {
      type: obj.objType.type,
      prop: obj.thatProp
    };
  }
}
```

You can see that it works:

```
console.log(getProp({ objType: { type: "this" }, thisProp: "anything" })); // {type: "this", prop: "anything"};
console.log(getProp({ objType: { type: "that" }, thatProp: "something" })); // {type: "that", prop: "something"};
```

---

The idea is that `nestedDiscrim(obj, { objType: { type: "this" } })` walks down through `obj`, looking at the `obj.objType.type` and comparing it against `"this"`.  If they are the same, then we narrow `obj` from `ThisObject | ThatObject` to just `ThisObject`.  Otherwise, we narrow `obj` from `ThisObject | ThatObject` to just `ThatObject`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoCeADigN4BQyyYxEAXMgORgAWwAzo8gD5OtxhGAbnIBfcuVCRYiFAGUA9gFsIGbLmQUqCrIRIM1OfLTESp0eEmR427QxogAPSCAAm7ZIpX2wm5Dsw9ej8afT5bLlEhalsABSgFIgZGOBACVlAAc0jJcAtZaxYBH2QnF3dPZVUsIz8AoIZSalpk-kFkKJiBeMTk9iqMkGyOiRgAVxBcYAUQZBAIdkhXABEOBChgJQAePFLnCDcPANreHpIoGgBpCAIAGmRlvfKjmo1ThPOrm4A+AApKZAANzgABsGHh7q41hslKBUmAGMsAJQMYEg5AcZAAUWcUEQYB292W3xE40mYGms3miwgK2hm1+aIYqTuyCh7HWmzh4GZaSRmgBwBgyF+v1CEAUwrRyAAvHLkAAiY64BX8gBkapF4slbPpsJA8Nl8qVrzAqv5WioyBgCigIpBEF8AGsMbN2Zz9fCLQCrRjhb8AIS-F2gIGgpH8qCOsZQWbwEHsCAiX1UIUigPUparDkwxmggDaToAupC9dywIWixHkFGwDG46DE8mreJfbX69QoGMkwDW36RWLaDrpQHjcqzerNYOSDr3TDy8hRzLFePzQK29HY2H0XLl3OuQbwM2++2t-Gm2JkBJyGSpjNkJlHWdfgFwbYSrwbMVTd7U-7M7S2Yei+WD3E09QtCEkEKhk7AKh0CFwB4CAzIs1aWlQp6zBhVrigwAQAHQQSQBHircPpWkQHz4VgpFxB8FFRL2pQJmQFFYeuKZ4f4tHERApG0ORKbIFRvQ8ZgdHdAxvpMVQ4jiOQKEgP0DoESCCiZL8j5gM+4G6JBTTcTBtjwaI9ywWcDAKiygyZKZEbRAA9I5mhGbBCr3KJSSKjZbBDAqTFKSp-HqZp2m6eJDRQWExkCKZ5lFDp1GKv0Ki2fZSJOS5pBuYlHkiclCqpY6fl2Ux14VUAA)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the `SomeObject` interface is not required. Here is a possible solution with the `SomeObject` interface eliminated:

[TypeScript playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgCoCeADigN4BQyVyYxEAXMgORgAWwAzk8gD7NtwwTANzkAvuXKhIsRCjzsOGbLmQQAHpBAATDmiw58dZBWo06jFoqaVqbTgAUoAeyKW4IAvZABzGxKlwaHgkZAVBZUM1TQgdPUjcQhITWypaEksBIVSaVkEnV0sOZwBbCG8-SQCYAFcQXGBnEGQfcoKiAApnLEYFTgSwXjC8sAGAShSzDgB3YDAEVmQurAA6dIgJ0zNqBDgOFCtOJnoc7eoocpqoZq2zu-MM5G7MNboAGlP76iIXNyfV+wcdqfM5iUT3Xb7fgjY4g7YXMBXG5w+7rRjPV4kD5fO4-Qr-F5ZYE4qhgnISMRAA)

```
interface ObjectType {
    type: 'this' | 'that';
}

interface ThisObject extends ObjectType {
    type: 'this'
    thisProp: 'anything'
}

interface ThatObject extends ObjectType {
    type: 'that'
    thatProp: 'something'
}

function getProp(obj: ThisObject | ThatObject) {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'this':
            return {
                type: obj.type,
                prop: obj.thisProp
            };
        case 'that':
            return {
                type: obj.type,
                prop: obj.thatProp
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `ObjectType` and the `objType` key. `objType` does not actually define the type of the interface. Here is a working example:

```
type ObjectType = 'this' | 'that'

interface SomeObject {
  type: ObjectType
}

interface ThisObject extends SomeObject {
  type: 'this'
  thisProp: 'anything'
}

interface ThatObject extends SomeObject {
  type: 'that'
  thatProp: 'something'
}

function getProp(obj: ThisObject | ThatObject) {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case 'this':
      return {
        type: obj.type,
        prop: obj.thisProp
      };
    case 'that':
      return {
        type: obj.type,
        prop: obj.thatProp
      };
  }
}
```