# Determine type of object by type of nested field in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have different types of logs. And each log has its name(action field)

```
type TLog1 = {
   action: "log1";
   additionalField1: string;
}
type TLog2 = {
   action: "log2";
   additionalField2: string;
}
type TAnyLog = TLog2 | TLog1;
```

If I have types like these, I can determine type of log by comparing its action with certain string

```
function myFunc(log: TAnyLog) {
   switch(log.action) {
      case "log1":
         console.log(log.additionalField1); // Typescript determines this log as TLog1
         return;
      case "log2":
         console.log(log.additionalField2); // Typescript determines this log as TLog2
         return;
   }
}
```

But if action is in nested object, it doesn't work;

```
type TLog1 = {
   nested: {
      action: "log1";
   }
   nestedAdditional: {
      additionalField1: string;
   }
}
type TLog2 = {
   nested: {
      action: "log2";
   }
   nestedAdditional: {
      additionalField2: string;
   }
}
type TAnyLog = TLog2 | TLog1;

function myFunc(log: TAnyLog) {
   switch(log.nested.action) {
      case "log1":
         console.log(log.nestedAdditional.additionalField1);
         // Typescript error, because TLog2.nestedAdditional doesn't have additionalField2
         return;
      case "log2":
         console.log(log.nestedAdditional.additionalField2); 
         return;
   }
}
```

Can I somehow determine type of parent object by its nested field?

Either its typescript limitations or I'm just missing something.

Comment: TS doesn't recognized "nested discriminated unions"; see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987786/typescript-determine-object-type-from-property-in-objects-property) and answer for more info; if I use the approach from there on your example I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WvkPnw).  Good luck!